# YAML error "yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here"

Tags: yaml, docksal

Error message: "ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
in "/Users/stalme/Localdev/cbnwebcms_salmen-dev/.docksal/docksal.yml", line 4, column 10
"

Yaml file:

```
version: "3.9"
db: 
  ...
  volumes: - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
  ...
```

Any idea why I'm getting the error message? I've checked the spacing, etc. and I'm still getting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use compact notation to start a sequence after an implicit key. Do this instead:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
db: 
  ...
  volumes:
    - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
  ...
```

I can't know for sure whether this fixes your problem as I don't know what `...` is.